# twilio doesn't play recorded voice message on server

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

Whenever I try to play a recorded voice message from phone, it does not get played during the twilio call using [verb `<play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) but it plays mp3 songs very well. What could be problem with the recorded voice message?

Comment: How are you trying to play the recorded voice message? What is the code you are using?

Comment: step1- we convert the recorded voice message to transfer it from Android phone to server .Step2 -than convert it back to the mp3 file to get it saved on server .Step3 - than just provide it to the verb example - <play> abc.net/this.mp3 </play>

Comment: OK, I'm not sure this is something that can be solved on StackOverflow. Could you email me at philnash@twilio.com with a sample recording that you can't play? Thanks

Comment: @philnash thanks .  Problem was solved by using the .wav format  instead of  .mp3  and android guy used some PCM format .

Comment: Great news! Give me a shout if there's anything else I can help with!

Comment: ok,it's good to see  you guys helping out .thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sumit, Megan from Twilio here.

Noticed you came to a solution above, but I wanted to point out the full [list of supported audio MIME types for the verb `<play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) and [some best practices for audio recordings](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/what-are-some-best-practices-for-audio-recordings), which seem to suggest WAV files over other types.